Converting macros to simple-text scripts
While tidying up my .vimrc I did some copy/paste operations that involved using bash terminal. This turned out to be a bad idea as it rendered all macros with control characters and special sequences useless. A simple example is this macro:
let @d="G:r!dinsert^M"

in which ^M represents carriage return (viewed in vim or similar editors ^M would be displayed in a different colour).
All was not lost. I managed to restore functionality of damaged macros by replacing 'remnants' of special sequences and control characters by their text representations. In this case:
let @d = "G:r!dinsert\<CR>"

Not an elegant or easy method. The good thing about this new all-text version is that it is no longer at the mercy of casual editing.
Is there a tool that can do this conversion? If not, is there a good lookup table that would make manual conversion easier?

Welcome to [vi.se]!

You can use keytrans() to translate characters into the Vim key syntax that you can use in a :map command.
You could use that to generate a mapping from your macro, for example:
:put ='nnoremap <Leader>d ' .. keytrans(@d)

(Note: this actually generates nnoremap <Leader>d G:r!dinsert<CR><NL> with a final <NL> at the end, because @d is set as a line-type register so pasting it produces an extra new-line that's not explicitly but that behavior is triggered because it ends in <CR>, this might not be what you want and it's possibly another reason to prefer mappings to macros. You could work around that one issue by using :call setreg('d', "G:r!dinsert\<CR>", 'c') to set it as a character-type register explicitly.)
If you want to keep it as a macro, you'll need to post-process that to escape the sequences, which you might be able to do by escaping < with \< on the result of keytrans(). You might also need to escape ", \ and other characters to make it a valid Vim string.
:let result = printf('let @d = "%s"', keytrans(@d)->escape('<"\'))
:put =result

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to further automate this, turn it into Vimscript functions, iterate over existing macro definitions or read them from a vimrc file, etc. Hopefully keytrans() is the one piece that's missing that will help you put it all together.

Thanks filbranden this is a very useful function to backup my macros. Would be nice to also find that lookup table to do the reverse, i.e. converting G:r!dinsert^M to G:r!dinsert<CR>

Not sure I follow you about lookup table, keytrans() will convert G:r!dinsert^M to G:r!dinsert<CR> which is only missing the backslash escape, so isn't that the translation you're looking for?

Print to terminal your .vimrc that includes a line like let @d="G:r!dinsert^M" and then copy/past from terminal back to your .vimrc, you will find that the above let command no longer works. Basically copy/past (outside vim) destroys special meaning of control characters such as ^M. To get your macro back from this 'dud' expression you need a lookup table that says ^M is ENTER (or ) etc.
